# jQuery addClass not working even while other methods work on the same object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, smarty

[Picture of my web form with side navigation menu shown on left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvjLf.jpg)

I am developing the website you see above in php and using Smarty templating engine to handle the display.

I am having a very strange issue that I cannot figure out the solution to.  One of the javascripts that I am using is from Materialize CSS.  This is for the side navigation menu which will automatically expand and contract when clicking the headers (Start, PXE, System).  According to the Materialize website (http://materializecss.com/collapsible.html) in order to have one of the headers automatically expanded, you simply add the "active" class to that element (see the "Preselected Section") on the Materialize link above.

Simple enough.  I try this in jQuery using the addClass method to no luck (code to follow).  Doing research here and around the web leads me nowhere, so I decide to start simple and choose an arbitrary element to add a class to, to make sure that I have a proper understanding of the addClass method and am using it correctly.

So I have this jQuery in a file called expandSideNav.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {   

    $(function(){
        alert("ExpandSideNav included");

        var el = $('h1');

        el.css("color", "orange");

        el.addClass('active');
    })
});
```

The "Stock Number" text in the center of the form is the only h1 tag and as you can see from the image above, the color of the text does in fact change to orange, however the  element never gets the "active" class added to it (see the actual rendered html from View Source in IE below).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="./img/icon/accept.png">

    <title>Configurator Tool</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="css/materialize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <!-- Jumbotron theme restricts container to 730px max -->
    <!--<link href="css/jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="./scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/additional-methods.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/materialize.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container divcontainer">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="./img/Arrow-Logo.png" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Arrow Logo"/>
            <span>&reg;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="mastercontainer">
            <div class ="leftnavbar">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked collapsible collapsible-accordion" role="tablist">
                    <li class="">
                    <a href="#" class="collapsible-header"><img src="./img/icon/Network Connection Router.ico" height="40" width="40" />Start</a>
                    <div class="collapsible-body">
                        <ul>                     
                            <li class="">
                                <a href="index.php?pagetitle=stocknumber.tpl"><img src="./img/arrow_v.png" height="40" width="40" />Stock Number</a>
                            </li>                    
                            <li class="">
                                <a href="index.php?pagetitle=#"><img src="./img/arrow_v.png" height="40" width="40" />StartPlaceholder1</a>
                            </li>                    
                            <li class="">
                                <a href="index.php?pagetitle=#"><img src="./img/arrow_v.png" height="40" width="40" />StartPlaceholder2</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                        <a href="#" class="collapsible-header"><img src="./img/icon/System.ico" height="40" width="40" />PXE</a>
                        <div class="collapsible-body">
                            <ul>                         
                                <li class="">
                                    <a href="index.php?pagetitle=timezone.tpl"><img src="./img/arrow_v.png" height="40" width="40" />Time Zone</a>
                                </li>                        
                                <li class="">
                                    <a href="index.php?pagetitle=#"><img src="./img/arrow_v.png" height="40" width="40" />PXEPlaceholder1</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                        <a href="#" class="collapsible-header"><img src="./img/icon/PCI-card_network.ico" height="40" width="40" />System</a>
                        <div class="collapsible-body">
                            <ul>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!-- leftnavbar -->
            <div class="rightcontent">
                <div id="rightcontentnonav">                                                                                                
                    <div class="welcome-header">
                        <h1>Stock Number</h1>
                        <h3>Entry Form</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div id="stocknum-content">    
                        <form id="stockNumForm" action="/IniGen_9_21_15/php/verifyStockPlaceholder.php" method="POST">
                            <label>Stock Number: </label>

                            <input id="stocknum" name="stocknum" type="text" value="" data-title="placehold"
                                   data-content="placehold" data-placement="bottom"
                                   data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="manual" onkeyup="ValidInputImage()" size="10" maxlength="8"/>

                        </form>    
                    </div>
                    <script src="./scripts/stocknum.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                    <script src="./scripts/expandSideNav.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                </div> <!-- rightcontentnonav --> 
                <a href="php/reset.php">Reset</a>
            </div> <!-- rightcontent -->               
            <div id="pager">
                <ul class="pager">
                    <li class="previous disabled">
                        <a class="disablelink" href="index.php?pagenav=-1"><span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span> Back</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="next">
                        <a id="nexLink" href="index.php?pagetitle=">Next <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!-- pager -->
        </div> <!-- mastercontainer -->
    </div> <!-- container -->
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

So I am confused by two things.

1. Why is it able to add the css styling in this function but not the addClass, when they are both operating on the same element and in the same function?  (I've tried placing that jQuery code both inside a generic function as seen here, and also outside a function just sitting in document.ready on its own)
2. The sidenavigation menu still works as is expected and is able to expand and contract.  When expanding, the materialize.min.js file that is included, expands the menu by adding the "active" class to the headers.  So why is that file able to use this method to add a class but my expandSideNav.js is not?

Remember my ultimate goal is to be able to add the "active" class to the "collapsible-header" elements, however I am using the code I've provided here to start small and try to figure out why the addClass method is not working as desired.

The materialize.min.js and materialize.js can be found at the Materialize CSS website linked above if needed.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: "View source" only shows the HTML markup as returned from the server.  To see generated content, you need to use the developer tools and inspect the element.  Try it out - I'm pretty sure the active class is being added!

Comment: I doubt that it's not adding the class. The more likely scenario is that the class is being added but the rules aren't applied due to a more specific rule or the same rule appearing later in the stylesheet. Use the debugger tools in the browser `<F12>` to see which styles are applied. With regards to `.css()` working, that function inlines styles which has a higher specificity than any external class definition will...

Comment: Wow I feel like a fool!  Thank you so much HaukurHaf!!!!  So I checked "Inspect Element" and it does add the active class.  Give me one second and let me try changing this to my desired functionality and see if it is working.  Will respond with update.

Comment: War10ck awesome!  Thanks!  I will try that as well.  I've wanted to use the <F12> functionality for debugging but have not taken time to research/learn how to use it.  I am not a trained web developer and am learning as I go.  I have figured that the debugger tools would save me a ton of time if I invested some time into learning to use them.

Comment: So you were both very correct in stating that the active class was being added.  So now I've changed my code to add the active class to the first "collapsible-header" class which according to the Materialize documentation (http://materializecss.com/collapsible.html) is all that needs to be done.  However I check "Inspect Element" and see that active class is indeed added however, that section is not automatically expanded.  So the first time I click the link, materialize.min.js removes "active" and nothing happens, the 2nd time I click the link the js adds "active" and the section expands???

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `active` class from all the list items and then add it to your element. May be two items are getting the same class. Hence the css rules might be getting overriden

Comment: Thanks Ekansh!  The guys that commented on my original question had the right solution.  The class was being added, I was just looking for it in the wrong location.  Thank you for taking a look at my question!

Answer (score 0):

Active class is indeed being added as per the method you used. Please verify, if there is a fault elsewhere.

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
$(function(){
    var el = $('h1');
    el.css("color", "orange");
    el.addClass('active');
})
});

.active{
   background-color:purple;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p12mfcvt/

**UPDATE**

In the link you provided, collapsible-head and collapsible-body are consecutive div elements, employ similar structure, and it must work. Alternatively, have the active class included by default. Keep it thus...

```
<div class="collapsible-header active"><a href="#"><img src="./img/icon/Network Connection Router.ico" height="40" width="40" />Start</a></div>

<div class="collapsible-body">Whatever you need in body</div>
```

Comment: You are absolutely right!  The class was being added, but I was looking for it in "View Source" when I should have checked out "Inspect Element".  Now I have a new problem relating to the same original question.  I've posted the new problem in the comments on my original question, since you seem to know what you're doing I'd love if you could take a look at it and give your input.  Thanks again.

Comment: I completely agree with you and this was a discrepancy that I never fully understood.  So in the Materialize documentation, I saw that they use nested divs for the collapsible portions.  However, I liked their side nav menu, and wanted to replicate it, so I did "Inspect Element" on that and it was structured as mine is, with "collapsible-header" in an "a" element and the following "collapsible-body" in a "div" element.  Any idea why their side nav menu would be like that?

Answer (score -1):

It could be that you're using addClass(), which looking at the jQuery documentation adds a class to an element, that has a class(es) already declared on the element. Here's what jQuery says

"It's important to note that this method does not replace a class. It simply adds the class, appending it to any which may already be assigned to the elements."

https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

You might want to try to render the h1 element with an empty class attribute, or a class in it which is a dummy. Failing that, have you tried this in your function...

el.attr('class','active');

Good luck.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the documentation.  addClass() does not add the same class *twice*.  It's perfectly OK and valid to use it to add a class to an element which has no classes.

Comment: I never said that it will add a class twice, I stated that, according to the documentation, it will add additional classes to classes that already exist. 

If it's fine to use it when no classes are already stated, then that helps to solve the question. Thanks.

Comment: Now you are misunderstanding me :-)  You said it will "add a class to an element, that has a class(es) already declared on the element." and then you suggested he add an empty class attribute to the element.  This is not required at all.  I was simply stating that that's not the case.  The part of the documentation you were referring to states that the class will not be added twice, not that the element needs to have classes already defined.

Comment: "It's important to note that this method does not replace a class. It simply adds the class, appending it to any which may already be assigned to the elements."

Append: add (something) to the end of a written document

Comment: Hey paulinthesky, thanks for giving your input and taking time to read and respond to my question.  The guys that commented on the original question pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Hi stEEvie, you're very welcome, glad you got the result you were seeking.